# Admob ads does not show up after linking - Failed to load ad: 0

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

My app is shown in admob after 2 days. Then, I linked my app to admob. But, Admob ads does show in the app. Also, everything was ok and working in test. Can you help me please? Should I wait for a while ?

I debugged app installed from Google Play on Android Studio and logs as follows:

> 03-02 21:27:25.468 22075-29561/? W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 403
>
> 03-02 21:27:25.478 29383-29394/? W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
>
> 03-02 21:27:25.488 29383-29383/? W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

Comment: check logs for admob in live app and update it in your question

Comment: There was an issue with some ads not showing up yesterday because of AWS being down. Are they showing today?

Comment: Admob still shows nothing. I added logs.

Comment: I released a new version. Before uploading Google Play I tested on my anroid device and it was working well. Then, I removed addTestDevice() lines and pushed Google Play. Now, it does not show up ads. My app has already linked as you know. May be, it takes some time to activate ads on production ? Because, this is my first app and first time I use admob ads. Please help me.

Comment: W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

Comment: Could you resolve the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Yes and I added answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by helping Google Admob Team. When I go to my AdSense account that warns me "Your ad units are not displaying ads because you haven't provided your account payments information yet.". I added a payment method and it works now.